# Is there a way to save invite codes in Stardew Valley Multiplayer?

Tags: stardew-valley

I purchased and play Stardew Valley through GoG, but my friend has it through steam. In order for us to play together, one of use has to provide an Invite code to the server every time we wish to enter the game.

Is there a way to save the server/invite code so we don't have to go through this hassle every time? Invite codes are randomly generated each session.

Maybe transfer the game from GoG->Steam or Steam->GoG so we can utilize the friend system if that's possible?

Comment: In general you can't "transfer" a game between services like this. However GoG does sometimes offer free GoG versions of certain games that people already own on Steam. That's not something GoG.com is currently doing for Stardew Valley but may do sometime in the future. Your best bet though is hoping that they come up with some better solution during this the beta period for GoG and Steam users to play together.

Answer (score 2):

As of patch 1.3 beta, there is no saving of invite codes.

There are a lot of forum posts asking for this, so this may change in the future.